# Mongoose query to list the document based on value from nested document

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

In this code i am trying to match the document based on product size from mongoose query.
I tried this query but it doesn't works. Can anyone tell me what's wrong in this code?

**Query i have passed:**
`{ $match: { "product_items.product_size": { value: 22, unit: "ml" } } }`

** Structure:**

```
  [
    {
            "product_name": "sample product",
            "product_items": [
                {
                    "product_item_number": "796363011028",
                    "product_size": {
                        "value": 22,
                        "unit": "ml"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work this way because `product_items.product_size` evaluates to an array of objects and you are trying to compare a single object with such array. It is more reliable to use [$elemMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/elemMatch/) when working with arrays of objects:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match: {
            "product_items": {
                $elemMatch: {
                    "product_size.value": 22,
                    "product_size.unit": "ml"
                }
            }
        }
    }
])
```

[Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FL_iQp7_EhO)